# What is the first short film completely made by AI?

Tags: reference-request, story-generation

I have created (not me exactly) a short film entirely made by AI. There many short films (like [Sunspring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LY7x2Ihqjmc&ab_channel=ArsTechnica)) 'written' by AI but were acted out by humans. In my short film, the story is by the AI, the music is by the AI, the title art is by the AI, the visuals and acting is by the AI (yes the AI can act) and the dialogue is by the AI. So, everything is AI. What I wanted to know is if this is the first one like this. I can't seem to find others online.

Comment: Hello. I suppose that you don't want to share your film for now. Right?

Comment: I didn't know about Sunspring, but I've just watched it, and it makes no sense: the actors and the director made their best to give any meaning to this non-sense. Rather than a science fiction movie, it looks more like either a comedy or a drama in a mental hospital (even a crazy person would say more sensical words and sentences than those generated by the AI) or maybe a dream but without making sense at all (i.e. dreams make more sense than that). [Here](https://www.docdroid.net/lCZ2fPA/sunspring-final-pdf) is the screenplay for those of you that want a big laughter due to non-sense.

Comment: @nbro I could share it if i wanted. But I want to know if it's the first of it's kind. It's not for the publicity (there's that too)... but I just wanna know